# React.StrictMode and createRoot influence my UI render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, gsap, react-strictmode

I am new to react. This is a generated code block in my project by create-react-app

```
const container = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(container);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Now I am using gsap to render anime. There is a disgusting blank block at the top of the page. Finally I found out the reason is these code, I also find out the solutions, but I do not know why.

###### 1. `ReactDOM.render` with `<React.StrictMode>` success.

###### 2. `createRoot.render(<App />)` success.

###### 3. `createRoot.render()` with `<React.StrictMode>` FAILED.

Here is the [project](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-sunset-lfp4gs?file=/src/index.js:519-537)
Can anyone explain these differences?

---------Edit-----------
context is a solution, but it's broken again after add another `<div id='img2'>` for animation

Comment: It's because React's "Strict Mode" runs your useEffect twice in development, which results in a miscalculation transform style within [screen1 style](https://i.imgur.com/lnza1rR.png)  -- it's being set as ~300px, when it should be 0px. You can either ignore it as this will only happen in development OR you can use an `isMounted` ref to prevent the useEffect from running twice: [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-nova-pj52qf).

Comment: @MattCarlotta  Why using the legacy API `ReactDOM.render` with 'strict mode` works well?  useEffect  not run twice in this API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`gsap.context()`](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/GSAP/gsap.context()) documentation:

> `gsap.context()` works around the React 18 "double-call of `useEffect()` in Strict Mode" issue that normally breaks `from()` logic - just call `revert()` on the Context in your `useEffect()` cleanup function:

```
import { gsap } from 'gsap';
import { ScrollTrigger } from 'gsap/ScrollTrigger';
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import './App.css';
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

function App() {
    const ref = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const ele = ref.current;
        let ctx = gsap.context(() => {
            gsap.fromTo(
                ele.querySelector('#img1'),
                {
                    opacity: 0,
                    x: -100,
                },
                {
                    opacity: 1,
                    x: 100,
                    scrollTrigger: {
                        trigger: ele.querySelector('.screen1'),
                        start: 'top top',
                        end: 'bottom center',
                        scrub: true,
                        pin: true,
                        markers: true,
                    },
                },
            );
        });
        return () => ctx.revert();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div ref={ref}>
            <div className="screen1">
                <div id="img1">load img</div>
            </div>
            <div className="screen2"></div>
            <div className="screen3"></div>
            <div className="screen4"></div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-76601768-394f6j)

Comment: I have update in my codesandbox, It's broken again after add another box for animation

Answer (score 0):

Should use ScrollTrigger in this way

```
    const main = useRef(null);
    const tl = useRef()

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        let ctx = gsap.context(() => {
            tl.current = gsap.timeline({
                scrollTrigger: {
                    trigger: '.screen1',
                    start: 'top top',
                    end: '+=200',
                    scrub: true,
                    pin: true,
                    markers: true,
                }
            })
                .fromTo(
                    '#img1',
                    {
                        opacity: 0,
                        x: 0
                    },
                    {
                        opacity: 1,
                        x: '20%',
                    })
                .fromTo(
                    '#img2',
                    {
                        opacity: 0,
                        x: '100%' 
                    },
                    {
                        opacity: 1,
                        x: '80%',

                    })
        }, main);
        return () => ctx.revert();
    }, [])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).